# How to ignore timestamp of the files while performing diff operation

Tags: diff, verification, integrity

I created a file named me.txt with text "This is dummy text", then made tar out of it and named me.txt.tar.
Now after a minute I again created a file with exactly same name and the text (basically I just did `touch me.txt`), then made tar out of it called me2.txt.tar.

Technically both the tars have same file with same file contents but time of creation of file me.txt is different. But the diff tool is saying:

> Binary files me.txt.tar and me2.txt.tar differ

This is because of reason of timestamp difference of file creation. But I just want to compare the contents of file and need to ignore the timestamp & hence I expect no output from the diff.

Please help me to ignore the timestamp of the files inside a tar or jar etc. as my concern is towards the contents of files.

The commands I used are :

```
$ echo "This is dummy text" > me.txt
$ tar -cvf me.txt.tar me.txt
(After 1 minute or so..)
$ touch me.txt 
$ tar -cvf me2.txt.tar me.txt
$ diff me.txt.tar me2.txt.tar
```

output:

**Binary files me.txt.tar and me2.txt.tar differ**

Even diffoscope gives similar output.

Comment: I tried this with your exact steps and I'm *not* getting "Binary files me.txt.tar and me2.txt.tar differ"

Comment: This is on linux. Maybe it's platform specific. Perhaps you could try to do a diff of the hexdump for each file to see if there's really not a difference between the two?

Comment: @Evert did you wait for a minute or so before making touch to the me.txt file?

Comment: Yes, I followed all the steps.

Comment: diff <(xxd me.txt.tar) <(xxd me2.txt.tar)    
gives output as : 
`9,10c9,10
< 00000080: 3030 3030 3032 3300 3134 3131 3533 3037  0000023.14115307
< 00000090: 3630 3100 3031 3037 3037 0020 3000 0000  601.010707. 0...
---
> 00000080: 3030 3030 3032 3300 3134 3131 3533 3130  0000023.14115310
> 00000090: 3131 3500 3031 3037 3031 0020 3000 0000  115.010701. 0...`

Comment: Well, that's really hard to read in a comment (there is an edit button), but that suggests that the files themselves are different.

Comment: Which platform you tried on? not Linux?

Comment: I mentioned I was on linux almost immediately and ask you what you were running.

Comment: I'm on Linux- Ubuntu

Comment: By default diff checks the timestamp of files in the jars, tars etc.. 
Then why are you not getting any output from diff?